# How capture max code or generator value if table has no rows

Tags: c#, winforms

This code works: `"SELECT MAX(" + sFieldName + ") AS MAXCODE FROM " + sTableName;`
The problem is when table has no rows, so it doesn't return nothing and I need to show for my user what will be the next code.

I also tried `"SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_PESSOA, 1) AS MAXCODE FROM " + sTableName;`
Same result, works only if has rows, otherwise it doesn't return nothing...

Sample of my code:

```
public int GetProximoCodDaTabela(string sFieldName, string sTableName)
{
    int iCodigo = 0;

    try
    {
        FbCommand commandAux = new FbCommand();
        commandAux.Connection = DM.getFbConexao;
        commandAux.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(" + sFieldName + ") AS MAXCODE FROM " + sTableName;
        //commandAux.CommandText = "SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_PESSOA, 1) AS MAXCODE FROM " + sTableName;
        FbDataReader readerAux = commandAux.ExecuteReader();

        while (readerAux.Read())
        {
            iCodigo = Int32.Parse(readerAux["MAXCODE"].ToString());
        }

        return iCodigo + 1;
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
        return iCodigo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not trying to generate your own unique value for a Primary Key are you?

Comment: Well, looks like I was, but in this line I'm not: `"SELECT MAX(" + sFieldName + ") AS MAXCODE FROM " + sTableName;`

Comment: Still doesn't working when there's no rows in my table.

Comment: `iCodigo = Int32....ToString());`  ToString?  Hope your fields and tables don't have spaces.

Comment: The design itself has a bad smell to it. I'd question the reason why the user has to know what the next "code" will be. In any case, this will never work in a multi-user environment, where another user is sure to come and generate a new row in the meantime. Rethink your design.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I didn't found a official answer but I made this work. Just insert a new register in your table, make the select and then delete the register. Working fine!